# Does the order of a differential equation necessarily equal the number of arbitrary constants in the general solution?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Consider the differential equation $(y')^2+3y'+2=0$.
The general solution seems to be $(y+x+c1)(y+2x+c2)=0$ with effective two arbitrary constants.But the order of the equation is 1.

Can this discrepancy be avoided?Or is there some clause in the law relating order to the number of constants which i am missing?

Comment: Certainly, if you have an $n$th order homogeneous linear equation with constant coefficients, then you have $n$ linearly independent solutions

Comment: Actually i was talking of the specific case described below the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your differential equation is effectively two differential equations:
$y' = -1$ and $y' = 2$.  Each has its own general solution with one arbitrary constant: $y = -x + c$ for the first, $y =2x+c$ for the second. 
The rule that the number of arbitrary constants is equal to the order applies to differential equations where $y^{(n)}$  is expressed as a function of $x, y, y', \ldots, y^{(n-1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=y'$. So $$y'^2+3y'+2=0\implies u^2+3u+2=0\implies (u+1)(u+2)=0$$ So, you have either $$y'=-1\implies y=-x+c_1$$ $$y'=-2\implies y=-2x+c_2$$ But the differential equation is of first order : so, the is a single "integration" constant (this means that $c_1=c_2=c$)

Comment: what if I said c2=2*c1 .Or c2=3*c1.All such families should be considered solutions as there is only 1 constant involved in them